# Añadir enlace en barra de navegación de Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Estoy usando una barra de navegacion básica de Bootstrap y no consigo crear un enlace para un botón que tiene submenús; la idea es que este enlace ejecute una función y al mismo tiempo despliegue el submenú que tenga.

Dejo el código copiado tal cual de la web de Bootstrap.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- El logotipo y el icono que despliega el menú se agrupan
       para mostrarlos mejor en los dispositivos móviles -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Desplegar navegación</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logotipo</a>
  </div>
 
  <!-- Agrupar los enlaces de navegación, los formularios y cualquier
       otro elemento que se pueda ocultar al minimizar la barra -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Enlace #1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Enlace #2</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Menú #1 <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Acción #1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Acción #2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Acción #3</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Acción #4</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Acción #5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
 
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>
    </form>
 
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">Enlace #3</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Menú #2 <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Acción #1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Acción #2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Acción #3</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Acción #4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Por ejemplo, que al ejecutar *menú #1* se ejecute una función y después muestre el submenú o al revés.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

podrías hacerlo de 3 maneras, una mediante jquery algo así:

```
$("#dropdown1").click(function() {
    alert("Ejecutar function");
});
```

obviamente añadirías un id diferente para cada enlace de dropdown, y también lo puedes hacer directo en las etiquetas de enlace, ya sea utilizando el atributo `onclick="myFunction()"` o el mismo atributo `href="javascript:myFunction()"`

y asi seria la función:

```
function myFunction() {
    alert("myFunction ha sido ejecutada");
}
```